# Windows Phone 8 - images show correctly in XAML designer, application crash on device

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, windows-phone-8

So, the problem is like this:

I've created a folder in solution explorer, called Images, and I've added some .png's, so the file structure looks pretty much like this: /MyProject/Images/image.png. In file properties, Build Action is set to Content, and Copy to Output is set to Copy always.

I'm trying to display an image like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="*" Width="*"/>
```

As I'm trying to display an image in a long list selector, I've made a sample data for designer:

```
<vm:MainViewModel.Items>
    <vm:ItemViewModel PageName="page1"  ImageUri="/Images/image1.png"/>
    <vm:ItemViewModel PageName="page2"  ImageUri="/Images/image2.png"/>
</vm:MainViewModel.Items>
```

In the  XAML designer, everything looks ok. The list is shown exactly like I want it to - an image, and text next to it.

In code, I'm adding the images like this:

```
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { PageName = "page1", ImageUri = new Uri(@"/Images/image1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
```

However, when I try to launch the application on the device. I'm met with following exception:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

and following stacktrace:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
```

Of course, when I comment out the Image in XAML, leaving only the text, the application crashes no more. So, how can I build in these images, and how can I retrieve them later?

Answer (score -1):

put all your images in the ClientBin folder(this is under project_name.Web folder) and then refer them like bellow it will work.

```
  <vm:ItemViewModel PageName="page1"  ImageUri="image1.png"/>
```

Comment: There is no such folder in my project

Comment: ClientBin is for Web projects, not phone projects.

Comment: thank you @Joe. I hadn't worked on phones but when I have the same issue with web project it really worked.